# Control order of script concatenation using Brunch

Tags: brunch

What is the best practice for controlling the order in which scripts / stylesheets are concatenated when using Brunch?

A simple version of my problem involves an application using Twitter Bootstrap, which requires jQuery.  Bootstrap requires that jQuery is loaded first.

Initially I had the following in my vendor/ directory:
`jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`

Which was concatenated by Brunch into my vendor.js file in alphabetical order, namely, bootstrap first.

To solve this I appended a number to the beginning of each script to designate the order in which I wanted them to concat -- `1-jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and `2-bootstrap.min.js`

I haven't been able to find information on how to do this more elegantly but I can't imagine that's the best way to accomplish this.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set order of concatenation in config

http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-

Comment: Much appreciated - I was apparently too tired to review the clear documentation on that.