# ChaplinJS + Brunch, can I produce only one JS file?

Tags: coffeescript, pack, brunch, chaplinjs

I would like to optimize the loading time of my website which is built on Chaplin + brunch (coffeescript).
How could I pack everything so that only one js file would be seen / loaded by the browser ?

It is mainly a workflow question, I don't know if this can be achieved by brunch itself or if I should rely on an external package such as webpack or even jspm.

Comment: There are [some questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896064/how-can-i-tell-brunch-not-to-concatenate-javascript-files) question which say that [brunch concatenates files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474236/control-order-of-script-concatenation-using-brunch) so I think you can try with the configuration posted there or use [some plugin](https://github.com/kenhkan/concat-brunch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does it: `config.files.javascripts.joinTo = 'app.js'`

http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-

Comment: Good, and then I guess I should refactor the code and only import this file while in production ?